# connecting to oracle with spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database using Spring and Hibernate. I can confirm connection to the database via Application Express.  Here is the exception:

```
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v1.3.3.RELEASE)[0;39m

[2m2016-05-03 13:38:13.997[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mapp.Application                         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Application on DESKTOP-RQ71JJA with PID 1172 (C:\Users\mworkman02\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\gs-rest-service-initial\target\classes started by mworkman02 in C:\Users\mworkman02\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\gs-rest-service-initial)
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:14.000[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mapp.Application                         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:14.051[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3b2c72c2: startup date [Tue May 03 13:38:14 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:14.959[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:15.270[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mtrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bean 'application' of type [class app.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7578475a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:15.341[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mtrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9bed72b2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:15.727[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8181 (http)
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:15.737[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service Tomcat
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:15.738[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:15.846[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:15.846[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.context.ContextLoader           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1801 ms
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.200[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.204[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.204[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.204[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.204[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.262[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:8080/xe
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.324[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.339[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.430[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.432[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.cfg.Environment           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.434[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.cfg.Environment           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:16.581[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:22.692[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : IO Error: Got minus one from a read call
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:22.712[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:22.717[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000063: The Oracle9Dialect dialect has been deprecated; use either Oracle9iDialect or Oracle10gDialect instead
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:22.718[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000064: The OracleDialect dialect has been deprecated; use Oracle8iDialect instead
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:22.720[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:22.755[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:22.917[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
[2m2016-05-03 13:38:28.925[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m1172[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:368) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:294) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:517) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) [spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319) [spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at app.Application.main(Application.java:73) [classes/:na]
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Got minus one from a read call
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:286) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:287) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Here is the class that is tring to connect:

```
package app;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import app.domain.AComponentScanBasePackageDomain;
import app.jparepository.AComponentScanBasePackageJpaRepository;
import app.service.AComponentScanBasePackageService;
import app.web.AComponentScanBasePackageWeb;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;






@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {AComponentScanBasePackageDomain.class, AComponentScanBasePackageJpaRepository.class, AComponentScanBasePackageService.class, AComponentScanBasePackageWeb.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
       em.setDataSource(dataSource());
       em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "app.jparepository" });

       JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
       em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
       em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

       return em;
    }



    //"jdbc:oracle:thin:http://127.0.0.1:8080:XE"
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
       dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:8080/xe");
       dataSource.setUsername( "Username" );
       dataSource.setPassword( "PASSWORD" );
       return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
       JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

       return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
       return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    Properties additionalProperties() {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
       return properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is probably here: https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle/
From a glimpse I see a different `Driver` and he uses the `OracleDataSource` instead of the regular `DataSource`. As a sidenote: Consider stop creating your own entitymanager, spring boot handles this all for you using `@Service` and `@Repository` annotations as the guide in the link also illustrates

Comment: Might be some problem with configuration XML file... Can u post ur XML ?

Answer (score 0):

This JDBC URL

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:8080/xe"
```

is your problem.

Oracle uses the port 1521, not 8080

So you need to use

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/xe"
```

as your JDBC URL.

Comment: That's of course correct for default oracle db server port. Unless of course it's explicitly configured to use port 8080 :)